# Why this error : cannot load m3u8 crossdomain access denied (JWplayer 7.12.6)

Tags: jwplayer7

I am facing the issue with Jwplayer(7.12.6) to loading .m3u8 video and getting this error message "cannot load m3u8 crossdomain access denied".

And  lot of R&D I found replace the url like

```
  {file: "https://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/xxxxxx.m3u8"}

To

  {file: "https://cdn.jwplayer.com/manifests/xxxxxx.m3u8"}
```

but the issue has been resovled some of the user system browser. now other user having same issue. still we can not replicate that issue on particular video.

We are using below code to play video of jwplayer

```
    jwplayer("video416").setup({
     sources: [
      {file: "https://cdn.jwplayer.com/manifests/xxxxxx.m3u8"},
      {file: "https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/XXXXX.mp4"}
    ],    
    image: "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/university-video-   cdn/Containers_101_img.jpg",
autostart: false,
controls:true,
controlbar:true,
displayclick:'play'    ,
icons: 'false',
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
primary: "HTML5"    
});
```

Can you please suggest how to allow or any sotuion to optimize this issue for JWplayer(7.12.6).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write your own sources: [ ] array for videos that you are hosting on your JW Player account. My suggestion would be to request the JSON URL from their Delivery API. It contains all the metadata (multiple sources, title, image, etc) that they know about this video:

```
jwplayer("video416").setup({
   playlist: '//cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/xxxxxxx',
   image: "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/university-video-cdn/Containers_101_img.jpg",
   autostart: false,
   controls:true,
   controlbar:true,
   width: '100%',
   aspectratio: '16:9', 
   primary: "HTML5"    
});
```

And you should use `aspectratio` instead of `height` since most web browsers will not like height set to 100%

You can read more about their Delivery API at https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/delivery-api-reference/

Comment: Todd, Actually the issue is single video  not playlist but the files like (xx.mp4, xx.m3u8) for different bandwidth. some of ther users noticed that their  are getting issue "cannot load m3u8 crossdomain access denied" . any suggestion on this.

Comment: Yes, it seems counterintuitive that you must use `playlist` when it is a single video, but that is the way it works. See their documentation at https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/ for more details.

The "crossdomain access denied" error sounds like a red herring, since all the CORS headers on JW's servers allow requests from all domains. Do you have a link to a page where I can reproduce this error?

Comment: Todd, We have checked on cross platform but we could not replicate that issue. also some of the users notice that their are facing issue out side our organization like "crossdomain access denied". we assume that they have some firewall issue on their system. is that possible it may cause the proxy or firewall?. Please suggest if any other option.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is caused by one of JW's CDN providers being blocked by your users' firewall or content blockers. Do you have a list of JW media IDs that are working fine and others that are causing this error? I would get that list and then submit them to support@jwplayer.com so they can escalate the error.

Comment: I also just noticed that you are using JW7. Have you tested in JW8? And does your page load via HTTP or HTTPS? If your user's browser requires Flash for HLS playback, then you might get a crossdomain error when you load an HTTPS video URL on a page that is HTTP.

Comment: We have tested in JW7 only and HTTPS page. Can you please suggest what are those scenario which we need to follow on User system

Comment: Ask your user to test this page: http://dashtodd.com/jwplayer/cdn-test.html
If the player shows an error, a link to another test video will appear below the player. If clicking on that link does not load the MP4 directly in the browser, then the issue is caused by a network filter or content blocker on their local network. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @Todd  for helping out , I will let you know any response in the provided URL, on user network.